# Manipulating json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm a beginner in javascript and trying to convert json object to list. Any logic would help me.

Converting this:

```
let obj = { "first_key": [  1, 2, 3, 4 ]
          , "second_key":[ 11,22,33,44 ]
}
```

to  this:

```
  [ { "first_key": 1, "second_key": 11 } 
  , { "first_key": 2, "second_key": 22 } 
  , { "first_key": 3, "second_key": 33 } 
  , { "first_key": 4, "second_key": 44 } 
  ]
```

What I have tried:

```js
let obj = {
  "first_key": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "second_key": [11, 22, 33, 44]
}

let new_obj = {};
let list = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  new_obj[key] = {};
  list.push(obj);
});

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Can you post what you've already tried? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not getting this.

Comment: I don't know why this was closed, anyways you need to use `reduce` to do this, it's actually a good question for someone starting now.

Comment: Have you tried using a simple `for` loop through `first_key` and use the index `i` to get the corresponding `second_key`? Please read: [How much effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: @MattiaRasulo it was closed because OP hasn't posted their effort

Comment: @adiga you (or who closed this) wrote that it needs more focus, the question is actually focused!

Comment: @MattiaRasulo that's the new close reason. Earlier it used to be known as "Too Broad"

Comment: Why did you close? Open it. I'll post that I have tried

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add your code there

Comment: ok. 1min I'll add it

Comment: @adiga you still didn't open, I'm waiting.

Comment: How to do it? Anyone?

Comment: welcome to SO, take a short tour to understand basic rules of this "community" -> https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

with a little practice it becomes almost automatic ...

```js
let obj = { "first_key":  [  1,  2,  3,  4 ]
          , "second_key": [ 11, 22, 33 ,44 ]
          }

convert = Object
            .keys(obj)
            .reduce((acc, eKey)=>{
               obj[eKey].forEach((elm,i)=>{
                 if (!acc[i]) acc[i] = {}
                 acc[i][eKey] = obj[eKey][i]
               }) 
               return acc
             },[])

//proof:
 convert.forEach((elm, i)=>console.log(`convert[${i}] =`, JSON.stringify(elm)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've stated you're a beginner, here is a less complex solution that should hopefully be easier to understand. I've added comments for clarification as well.

```js
let obj = {
  "first_key": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "second_key": [11, 22, 33, 44]
}

let keys = Object.keys(obj);
let new_arr = [];
//we need as many objects in the new_arr as there are values in the obj.first_key array
for(let i = 0; i < obj[keys[0]].length; i++) {
  //there is one new object for each element in the array
  let new_obj = {};
  //for each key in the object, set the value on new_obj
  //to the value at the corresponding index 'i'
  keys.forEach(key => {
    new_obj[key] = obj[key][i];
  });
  new_arr.push(new_obj);
}

console.log(new_arr);
```